# I am having trouble with an IF statement setting a variable to True and False

Tags: python, if-statement, random, while-loop, flags

So, I am trying to create a simple lottery machine that keeps picking numbers until you win. I select my lottery number (**my_number**) and then compare it to a list of 4 possible winning numbers (**winning_numbers**) which I pick using the function "**pick_winning_numbers**".

I have set up a while loop which runs until the flag equals True. This is set by the function "**compare numbers**" except that it never changes the flag. No matter what the while loop always keeps running.

I have tried taking the if statement out of the function, I have tried taking the while loop out, I have tried rewriting the code 5 times. None of it has helped. Please help me as I have spent so many hours of my life on this. Code below.

```
from random import choice

def pick_winning_numbers():
#puts 4 numbers into a list and makes sure that they arent duplicates
    while len(winning_numbers) <4:
        chosen_number = choice(possible_numbers)
        if chosen_number not in winning_numbers:
            winning_numbers.append(chosen_number)

def compare_numbers():
    #Compares the number that I picked to the list of winning numbers and sets the flag to true or false
    if my_number in winning_numbers:
        print(f"Congratulations, you have won")
        flag = False
    else:
        flag = True

possible_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
my_number = 7
winning_numbers = []
counter = 0
flag = True

while flag == True:
    pick_winning_numbers()
    print(winning_numbers)
    compare_numbers()
    print(flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the array **winning_numbers** storage the same elements always. For that reason, if the array **winning_numbers** doesn't contain the winning number **7** the program will loop.

You have to clear the **winning_numbers** array each time the loop works.

You should do something like this:

```
def pick_winning_numbers():

    global winning_numbers
    winning_numbers = []

    while len(winning_numbers) <4:
        chosen_number = choice(possible_numbers)
        if chosen_number not in winning_numbers:
            winning_numbers.append(chosen_number)
```

It's necessary use **global winning_numbers** inside the method, if you don't do that, the array **winning_numbers** will be part from the method (as a local variable) and not from the whole code.

Also inside the `compare_numbers()` method you have to add the `flag` variable as global:

```
def compare_numbers():
    global flag
    if my_number in winning_numbers:
        print(f"Congratulations, you have won")
        flag = False
    else:
        flag = True
```